# Data Type Search from Input File

Tags: python, list, input

I’m trying to find int values in an inputted list that contains floats and int values. The problem is the list read in looks like this:

```
List = [“14”,”8.00”,”2.00”,”3”]
```

How would I go about finding just the integer values in this list, not the floats? I’m presuming the type function won’t work since it’ll just say all the numbers are strings.

Comment: what have you tried so far? please share your code

Comment: you could either check the type of each item an keep the ones where type is `int` or convert the item to an integer and check if it's equal to the original item ;-)

Comment: "I’m presuming the type function won’t work since it’ll just say all the numbers are strings." Well, yes. There *aren't* any integer values in your list, nor any floats. So what are you *actually* trying to find? Well, you're trying to find strings, but only certain ones, ones that meet a certain rule. Can you think of a way to write the rule in Python code? Can you think of a way to test all the things in a list to see whether they meet a rule?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ast` module to identify the integer and float from strings.

```
In [16]: type(ast.literal_eval("3"))                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[16]: int

In [17]: type(ast.literal_eval("3.0"))                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[17]: float
```

Now using this concept with `isinstance`, you can filter out the integers:

```
In [7]: import ast 

In [10]: a = ['14','8.00','2.00','3']                                                                                                                                                                       

In [11]: a                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[11]: ['14', '8.00', '2.00', '3']

In [12]: res = []                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [13]: for num in a: 
    ...:     if isinstance(ast.literal_eval(num),int): 
    ...:         res.append(num) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [14]: res                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[14]: ['14', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
l = ["14","8.00","2.00","3"]
l = [int(i) for i in l if i.isdigit()]
print(l)
```